# Location Services App - Xcode "Stop" leaves location services running forever

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

Here's a strange one.. I'm writing a set of apps that use location services - some in the background, some only in the foreground - and for the most part, when not requiring background locations, I'm careful to stop my CLLocationManager updates whenever the app goes into the background.

I've noticed that by stopping my debug builds in Xcode 7.3 using the stop button, these apps get stuck using location services permanently - in order to be sure GPS is not being used I need to restart the apps and then close them the way a user would.

Here's the gist:

- Closing the apps with the home button **turns off** location services, whether started from Xcode or from springboard. (I see the location symbol disappear from the status bar after ~10 seconds.)
- Force-closing the apps, by double-tapping home and swiping them off screen, **turns off** location services, whether started from Xcode or from springboard
- Closing the apps with Xcode's Stop button ***leaves location services running forever.***

And the super weird part:

- Restarting the iPhone after getting to that stuck state **also** leaves location services running forever!

The only way forward is to restart the apps after I finish work, then background them, or my phone loses 10% battery per hour. I've seen this phenomenon in devices running iOS8 and iOS9.

Anyone else notice this behaviour? Or more to the point, are there any Xcode configuration possibilities to avoid this?

Comment: What does it exactly mean to turn off or on location services? Which particular service you are referring to - region monitoring, standard location updates, significant location updates?

Comment: If you're asking me what I'm stopping in my code, I call stopUpdatingHeading, stopUpdatingLocation, and stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges. 

But if you're asking me what I mean by "turns off location services", I mean the iPhone appears to stops accessing GPS etc - it removes the little location icon from the top right of the status bar, stops showing the purple location icon next to my apps in Settings/Privacy/Location Services, and stops devouring battery power at 100 miles an hour :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure why this behavior is not expected to begin with. To stop significant location updates you must call *stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges* method. When you hit the stop button in Xcode, you just forcefully kill the app with none of your housekeeping code being executed. That means nobody tells location manager to stop doing what your app requested it to do, and when iPhone gets a new location, it launches your app to background mode and delivers that location reading to it.

I doubt you can do anything to change this behavior, as it essentially would mean teaching Xcode how to do a cleanup, which is specific for your app.

Re: "*little location icon from status bar*"

First of all, even if the arrow is solid, it does not necessarily mean the app keeps using GPS and aggressively drains phone battery. This arrow icon is about privacy, it is used to tell user that at least one app may learn about location *change* using method or methods other than or in addition to region monitoring.

Please keep in mind that the arrow is solid if one of the following services is active:

- standard location updates with GPS
- standard location updates without GPS
- significant location updates
- visit tracking

The reason I asked you which location service you use is that the last two services will resume on iPhone reboot and will not be interrupted if you kill the app. Standard location updates will not resume on phone reboot and will be cancelled on app termination.

Comment: Ok thanks, that answers my question. Now, as to why it wouldn't be expected to begin with - when I force close an app on my phone, that "cleanup" you mention happens - that is, my AppDelegate's appWillTerminate type methods get called. So I think it's quite reasonably to imagine that when you force-quit an app from the debugger, the iOS system might also call those methods. I admit it's also quite logical that it doesn't.

Comment: And your comment about it not *necessarily* draining the battery is good to know; however from experience it was draining it very aggressively. Life is better when those significant location updates are disabled :)

Comment: Mete, I have no idea what (and how) your code does, but whenever you see the battery drained rather aggressively, it is time to take a closer look at your code. CPU and radio (networking) hit battery the hardest. The location updates just trigger all that code. Monitoring for significant location changes is essentially toll free service.